# Return type void. Also need assistance with my function

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, void

I'm trying to program a function that allows me to locate a substring "from" in a string "src", and replace the "from" substring with the "to" substring in all cases, and output the new string through "dest"

```
void find_replace(char* src, char* from, char* to, char* dest)
{
  dest = (char * ) malloc(sizeof(src)+sizeof(from));
  char * stringcomb;
  int i;
  int j;
  stringcomb = strstr(src, from);
  strncpy(stringcomb, to, strlen(to));
  puts (src);
  return ;
}
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
   char* dest;

}
```

Comment: `sizeof(src) + sizeof(form)` is wrong, suppose there are `n` occurrences of `to` in the `src` string and `sizeof()` does not give you the length of the string, and you are still missing the space for the terminating `'\0'`, too many problems... And you just asked almost the same question a few minutes ago.

Comment: got it, so I switched it up to strlen(src)+strlen(from). Would that make much of a difference?

Comment: Your code won't compile. Missing a `}`. Also, `dest` is unused.

Comment: Hopefully you can help me, but I was thinking (and I didn't do it, because I wasn't too sure...) that I could do 
   dest = strstr(src, from);
   stringcpy(dest, to, strlen(to));
   puts (src) ;

Answer (score 3):

You have multiple problems with that piece of code:

- When you do `sizeof` on a pointer, you get the size of the pointer and not the size/length of what it points to. If you want to get the length of a string use `strlen`.
- You forget to allocate space for the terminating `'\0'` character.
- What if, like in your case, `to` is longer than `from`? Then you will allocate wrong.
- Arguments in C are passed *by value*, meaning they are copied and the function only have the copies and not the original. That affects your `dest` argument. To emulate pass by reference you must pass a pointer, in your case a pointer to the pointer.

And lastly:

- [In C you should not cast the return of `malloc`.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

And just to nitpick:

- You don't need an explicit `return` statement at the end of a function returning `void`, the compiler will implicitly handle it.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to provide that we were allowed to make the assumption that "to" was not longer than "from". Changed the sizeof to lengthof, and accounted for the '\0'. Can you elaborate on your 4th point a little more? Thank you!

Comment: Could you elaborate on the "arguments in C" point a bit more? Thank you!

Comment: @LeehoLim If the argument `dest` in the function is a copy, and you change it, then you only change the copy and not the original. If you just search a little there are *thousands* of questions here on SO and elsewhere regarding passing pointers by reference.